# jQuery detecting when slide in menu, or his child has lost focus when navigating with tab

Tags: jquery, focus, accessibility, lost-focus

Hi guys I am looking for a solution to close a slide-in menu when navigating with keyboard (tabs or right and left arrows).

I can open the menu and navigate in it no problem. But I want to detect when the `$('#menu')` or any elements that is a child of `$('#menu')` lost the focus and close the slide-in menu by removing the class `$('.open')`.

I tried `$('#menu').focusOut()` but it only check the focus of the `$('#menu')` itself so when I am in child element like a `li` inside `$('#menu')` it close the menu, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: try using `blur`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works great for my case. When I click to open the menu, I add an Event Listener wich call the function onFocus.

The function check if the element who has the focus is a child of `$('#menu')` if not close the menu and remove the Event listener.

```
document.addEventListener('focusin', onFocus);

function onFocus(e) {
  if(!$('#menu').find(e.target).length) {
    $('#menu').fadeToggle();
    $('#menu').toggleClass("open");
    document.removeEventListener('focusin', onFocus);
  }
}
```